# Is it possible to show the multiselect dropdownlist in a local report on Webform Report Viewer?

Tags: reporting-services, localreport

When designing a Reporting Services report, and creating a multi-value parameter, a nice dropdown list with the possibility to select one or many items appear in the parameter pane.

Is it possible to show this type of control on a local mode report in the Web based Report Viewer?

I have tried to set ShowParameterPrompts="true", but no parameter pane appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can't get the parameter pane when using the web based report viewer in local mode. Local mode has the advantage of not requiring a full blown Reporting Services installation, but the drawback is that you need to do some more of the heavy lifting yourself. Local mode will take data and render it according to the report definition that you design, but you are responsible for going out and fetching that data yourself and providing it to the report viewer in the form of a dataset. This means you need to execute your SQL in code passing in any needed parameters. The advantage of doing "remote" processing is that all you really need to do is point the control to the URL of the reporting services server and tell it which report you want. The report server and control take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks. I did find that out from here also: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/30424/1954?pf=true

"In the absence of Report Server, the ReportViewer must obtain its data from your application. In local mode, your application is responsible for providing the necessary input to the report. That's why the ReportViewer doesn't display the parameter prompt area with local reports. Parameters and data are external to ReportViewer."